# Проблема при добавлении данных в HBase

Tags: hadoop

Всем привет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, при попытке покласть данные в HBase получаю ошибку:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1422734399.7071422734399.7071422734399.7071422734399.7071422734399.7071422734399.7071422734399.7071422734399.7071422734399.7071422734399.7071422734399.7071422734399.7071422734399.7071422734399.707142
```

Сам код такой:

есть mapper, который принимает на вход данные, парсит их и должен выгрузить в Hbase

```
#!/opt/anaconda/envs/bd9/bin/python

import sys
import happybase

def emit(uid, timestamp, url):
    sys.stdout.write('{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(uid, timestamp, url))

def emit2(uid, timestamp, url):
    connection = happybase.Connection('server')
    table = connection.table('name')

    b = table.batch(timestamp=(int(timestamp*1000)))

    try:
        b.put('uid:', {'cf:url': 'data:url'})
        raise ValueError('Something went wrong!')
    except ValueError as e:
        pass
    else:
        b.send()


def map(line):
    objects = line.split('\t')
    if len(objects) == 3:
        uid, timestamp, url = objects
        if len(uid) > 1 and len(url) > 1 and url.startswith('http') and int(uid) % 2 == 0:
            emit2(uid, timestamp, url)

def main():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        map(line.strip())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Содержимое таблицы должно представлять собой rowkey=uid и column=data:url. Отметка времени в базе должна совпадать с отметкой в файле, а не с моментом, когда запись попала в базу.

❗️Обратите внимание: отметку надо умножить на 1000 и привести к int: int(ts * 1000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Int скорее всего не поддерживает такие большие числа, измените тип.